# Create virtual product with custom options and dynamic price programmatically

Tags: magento2, create-product

How to create a virtual product programmatically and add custom option to it? And how to set the product price dynamic ?

Comment: you can follow this link(https://www.dckap.com/blog/how-to-programmatically-create-a-virtual-product-in-magento-2/) for basic product creation.
And you can also visit this for custom options (https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-product-programmatically.html)
But what do you mean by dynamic price?

Comment: If you want to add dynamic price and other few things dynamic you can create a command using this tutorial also(https://phpcodez.com/create-product-programmatically-magento-2/), You can add dynamic data using arguments of commands.